Efficient Query for Connecting (Indirect) Flights with SurrealDB
I'm testing on SurrealDB and attempting to query data from two tables: airport and flight. Here's the setup:
create |airport:1..10000| set 
    name = rand::string(5),
    country = rand::enum("VN", "USA", "China", "UK", "RUS"), 
    code = rand::string(8)
return none;

create |flight:1..40000000| set 
    flightno = rand::string(5),
    destinationid = type::thing("airport", rand::int(1,10000)),
    originid = type::thing("airport", rand::int(1,10000))
return none;

Given two input countries (e.g., "USA" as the origin and "China" as the destination), I need to fetch all flightno that involve exactly one stopover to travel from an airport in the origin country to an airport in the destination country. The output should include pairs of flightno values: one for the departing flight and one for the arriving flight. Flights that directly connect the origin and destination must be excluded (including in-country flights).
I have problem to find the most optimal and correct query as stopover logic requires joining flights on originid and destinationid.
Edit: I supposed this is more like a permutation problem. In MySQL, the code would be
WITH RECURSIVE array_elements_1 AS (
    SELECT 
        flightno AS element
    FROM 
        flight
    WHERE
        originid.country =="USA" and destinationid.country !="China"
),
array_elements_2 AS (
    SELECT 
        flightno AS element
    FROM 
        flight
    WHERE
        originid.country !="USA" and destinationid.country =="China"
)
SELECT 
    JSON_ARRAY(e1.element, e2.element) AS pair
FROM 
    array_elements_1 e1
CROSS JOIN 
    array_elements_2 e2;

So now, the issue is to translate this code to SurrealQL.

Stackoverflow is not a code writing/translation service ...
